# Initialization when running Junit Test case in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm writing test cases for service and util classes for my spring boot application. Following are snippets from the test cases

**FooServiceImplTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    //test cases for FooServiceImplTest
}
```

**BarUtilTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BarUtilTest {

    @Test
    //test cases for BarUtilTest
}
```

Now, when I run the test cases, I see something like the following in the console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

17:21:07.835 [main] INFO  c.c.l.s.impl.FooServiceImplTest - Starting FooServiceImplTest on Users-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 8944 (started by user in /Users/user/Documents/my-project)
17:21:07.836 [main] DEBUG c.c.l.s.impl.FooServiceImplTest - Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
17:21:07.836 [main] INFO  c.c.l.s.impl.FooServiceImplTest - The following profiles are active: prod
17:21:10.828 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Starting...
17:21:10.890 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Start completed.

...
// runs test cases for FooServiceImplTest

17:21:33.643 [main] INFO  c.c.l.s.impl.FooServiceImplTest - Started FooServiceImplTest in 40.898 seconds (JVM running for 102.231)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

17:21:49.290 [main] INFO  c.c.l.util.BarUtilTest - Starting BarUtilTest on Users-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 8944 (started by user in /Users/user/Documents/my-project)
17:21:49.290 [main] DEBUG c.c.l.util.BarUtilTest - Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
17:21:49.290 [main] INFO  c.c.l.util.BarUtilTest - The following profiles are active: prod
17:21:50.809 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-3 - Starting...
17:21:50.972 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-3 - Start completed.

...
// runs test cases for BarUtilTest
17:22:04.765 [main] INFO  c.c.l.util.BarUtilTest - Started BarUtilTest in 30.635 seconds (JVM running for 133.353)
```

So it looks like for every test suite I write, everything is initialized again. That may be one of the reasons that it is taking a lot of time to run the test cases as I add more test suites. Is there anyway to initialize everything once and run all test cases in one go?

Comment: You should try to keep Spring out of your unit tests. Otherwise they become integration tests and, yes, these are slow.

Comment: @UweAllner could you please elaborate what you mean by keep Spring out?

Comment: Do not annotate with SpringBootTest and RunWith, use autowiring in your components by constructor and not by field, so they can be called with mocks, where necessary. Then there is no need to start the ApplicationContext.

Comment: @UweAllner thanks I'll try this

Comment: Are your tests unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: @MadhuBhat they're unit tests

Comment: If they're unit tests, then you don't need to use @SpringBootTest.